# Material UI TabePagination Component: Differentiate between back and forward button clicks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to differentiate between back and forward button clicks in this component? I need to run different logic on these two different button clicks, but am having trouble figuring out if there is a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this buttons and add own logic for each. The `ActionsComponent`  prop of the `TablePagination` component allows the implementation of custom actions. See [Doc](https://mui.com/components/tables/#custom-pagination-actions). [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nmw5s?file=/demo.js)